# Making synchronous calls to Cloud Firestore when running off the main thread

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, coroutine

I am building an app based off of the Android Clean Architecture Kotlin version (https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture-Kotlin).

Using this architecture, each time you want to invoke a use case, a Kotlin coroutine is launched and the result is posted in the main thread. This is achieved by this code:

```
abstract class UseCase<out Type, in Params> where Type : Any {

abstract suspend fun run(params: Params): Either<Failure, Type>

fun execute(onResult: (Either<Failure, Type>) -> Unit, params: Params) {
    val job = async(CommonPool) { run(params) }
    launch(UI) { onResult.invoke(job.await()) }
}
```

In his example architecture, Mr. Android10 uses Retrofit to make a synchronous api call inside the kotlin couroutine. For example:

```
override fun movies(): Either<Failure, List<Movie>> {
            return when (networkHandler.isConnected) {
                true -> request(service.movies(), { it.map { it.toMovie() } }, emptyList())
                false, null -> Left(NetworkConnection())
            }
        }

private fun <T, R> request(call: Call<T>, transform: (T) -> R, default: T): Either<Failure, R> {
            return try {
                val response = call.execute()
                when (response.isSuccessful) {
                    true -> Right(transform((response.body() ?: default)))
                    false -> Left(ServerError())
                }
            } catch (exception: Throwable) {
                Left(ServerError())
            }
        }
```

'Either' represents a disjoint type, meaning the result will either be a Failure or the object of type T you want.

His service.movies() method is implemented like so (using retrofit)

```
@GET(MOVIES) fun movies(): Call<List<MovieEntity>>
```

**Now here is my question**. I am replacing retrofit with Google Cloud Firestore. I know that currently, Firebase/Firestore is an all async library. I want to know if anyone knows of a method more elegant way of making a synchronous API call to Firebase.

I implemented my own version of Call:

```
interface Call<T: Any> {
    fun execute(): Response<T>

    data class Response<T>(var isSuccessful: Boolean, var body: T?, var failure: Failure?)
}
```

**and my API call is implemented here**

```
override fun movieList(): Call<List<MovieEntity>> = object : Call<List<MovieEntity>> {
        override fun execute(): Call.Response<List<MovieEntity>> {
            return movieListResponse()
        }
    }

    private fun movieListResponse(): Call.Response<List<MovieEntity>> {
        var response: Call.Response<List<MovieEntity>>? = null
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(DataConfig.databasePath + MOVIES_PATH).get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            response = when {
                !task.isSuccessful -> Call.Response(false, null, Failure.ServerError())
                task.result.isEmpty -> Call.Response(false, null, MovieFailure.ListNotAvailable())
                else -> Call.Response(true, task.result.mapTo(ArrayList()) { MovieEntity.fromSnapshot(it) }, null)
            }
        }
        while (response == null)
            Thread.sleep(50)

        return response as Call.Response<List<MovieEntity>>
    }
```

**Of course, the while loop at the end bothers me.** Is there any other, more elegant ways, to wait for the response to be assigned before returning from the `movieListResponse` method?

I tried calling await() on the Task that is returned from the Firebase `get()` method, but the `movieListResponse` method would return immediately anyway. Thanks for the help!

Comment: All Firebase APIs for mobile and web clients are asynchronous.  Coroutines are actually all also asynchronous, but the compiler just makes them appear synchronous by internally restructuring your code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I found what I was looking for in the Google Tasks API: "If your program is already executing in a background thread you can block a task to get the result synchronously and avoid callbacks" https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks#blocking

So my previous problematic code becomes:

```
private fun movieListResponse(): Call.Response<List<MovieEntity>> {
        return try {
            val taskResult = Tasks.await(FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().
                    collection(DataConfig.databasePath + MOVIES_PATH).get(), 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            Call.Response(true, taskResult.mapTo(ArrayList()) { MovieEntity.fromSnapshot(it) }, null)
        } catch (e: ExecutionException) {
            Call.Response(false, null, Failure.ServerError())
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            Call.Response(false, null, Failure.InterruptedError())
        } catch (e: TimeoutException) {
            Call.Response(false, null, Failure.TimeoutError())
        }
    }
```

Note I no longer need my Thread.sleep while loop.
**This code should only be run in a background thread/kotlin coroutine.**

Comment: Beautiful, thanks for the link. Nice to find an answer which actually provides a way to use Tasks API in a blocking fashion! Whenever someone asks such a question, people overwhelmingly respond with **"that's not how you use async stuff!!!!!!!"** instead of "This is the way to block it, but please don't do it on main thread"...

Comment: @Sean Blahovici I'm trying to accomplish using `Tasks.await` in my tests, but I keep running into the error: `Must not be called on the main application thread`, despite wrapping the code in a `launch { }` block within a `runBlockingTest { }` Coroutine scope. Can you provide a full example on how to accomplish using Tasks.await in a test please?

I'm using Robolectric as well, if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Peter In that case, I would simply put the "hard to test" code like Tasks.await() behind an interface and mock its behavior. If you really want to test it, then I think you will want to use Instrumented tests, inject your target module directly in the integration test and test the behaviour that way.

Answer (score 1):

This is overengineered, there are several layers trying to do the same thing. I suggest you go back a few steps, undo the abstractions and get into the mood of using coroutines directly. Implement a `suspend fun` according to [this template](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-coroutines/blob/master/kotlin-coroutines-informal.md#wrapping-callbacks). You don't need the crutches of `Either`, handle exceptions in the most natural way: a `try-catch` around a `suspend fun` call.

You should end up with a signature as follows:

```
suspend fun movieList(): List<MovieEntity>
```

Call site:

```
launch(UI) {
    try {
        val list = movieList()
        ...
    } catch (e: FireException) {
        // handle
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a little over-engineered I agree, but my goal was to make my domain and presentation independent of Firebase.

Answer (score -1):

That's is not the way how firebase works. Firebase is based on callback.

I recommend architecture component's livedata.

Please check the following example.

here is a link: https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-with-firebase-907b7699f6a0

Comment: I use LiveData in the presentation layer. I am trying to decouple my presentation and domain layer from Firebase.